# ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation, autoencoder

I am trying to implement ID aware autoencoder by implementing ID regression in a convolutional variational autoencoder. I found out about this technique [here](https://dcase.community/documents/challenge2020/technical_reports/DCASE2020_Hayashi_111_t2.pdf). I have image input of shape `(128, 448, 1)` along with categorical input of shape `(6,)`. Here's a sample code I got from ChatGPT for the implementation:
**Encoder:**

```py
latent_dim = 2

x = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(image_inputs)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = concatenate([x, cat_inputs])
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(x)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim)(x)

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

z = Lambda(sampling)([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = Model([image_inputs, cat_inputs], [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
```

**Decoder:**

```py
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
x = Reshape((7, 7, 64))(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = concatenate([x, cat_inputs])
outputs = Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
decoder = Model([latent_inputs, cat_inputs], outputs, name='decoder')
```

**VAE:**

```py
vae_outputs = decoder([encoder([image_inputs, cat_inputs])[2], cat_inputs])
vae = Model([image_inputs, cat_inputs], vae_outputs, name='vae')

reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(image_inputs), K.flatten(vae_outputs))
reconstruction_loss *= 28 * 28
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
kl_loss *= -0.5
vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
```

When I implemented it, the `keras.layers.Concatenate` layer in the decoder produced error like:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 128, 448, 1), (None, 6)]
```

I don't know whether this is the right way to implement ID regression, but this is the only reference code I have found. How can I concatenate the image input and the categorical input when their shapes are different?

Comment: what is supposed to be "ID regression"?

Comment: also, you have not posted what is `concatenate`